# Android Tilting-Mind blowing

Tags: android, rotation, orientation

So here is my code if someone be kind enough to help out.

I want the orientation values to be displayed but all I get is 0.0 0.0 0.0 so I dont know whats going on I dont think its my phone becasue it fairly modern (HTC One V)

```
 package ple.x75;


 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
 import android.hardware.Sensor;
 import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
 import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
 import android.hardware.SensorManager;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.view.View;




 public class MainActivity extends Activity
{


private ImageView img;
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private float[] mAccelerometerReading;
private float[] mMagneticFieldReading;
private float[] mRotationMatrix = new float[16];
private float[] mRemapedRotationMatrix = new float[16];
private float[] mOrientation = new float[3];

// Register the event listener and sensor type.
public void setListners(SensorManager sensorManager, SensorEventListener mEventListener)
{
    sensorManager.registerListener(mEventListener, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    sensorManager.registerListener(mEventListener, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) this.getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    final Button btn_valider = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    final TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    final SensorEventListener mEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        }
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
                case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
                    mAccelerometerReading = event.values.clone();
                    break;

                case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
                    mMagneticFieldReading = event.values.clone();
                    break;
            }
            if(mAccelerometerReading != null && mMagneticFieldReading != null &&
                    SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(mRotationMatrix, null, mAccelerometerReading, mMagneticFieldReading))
            {
                SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(mRotationMatrix,
                        SensorManager.AXIS_Y, SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_X, mRemapedRotationMatrix);
                SensorManager.getOrientation(mRemapedRotationMatrix, mOrientation);
            }

        };
    };
    setListners(sensorManager, mEventListener);
    btn_valider.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            if(mOrientation != null)
            {
                final CharSequence test;
                test="Results: "+mOrientation[0]+" "+mOrientation[1]+" "+mOrientation[2];
                txt1.setText(test);
            }
            else{
                final CharSequence test;
                test="Results: Apparently Nothing...";
                txt1.setText(test);
            }
}
 });
}
}
```

Comment: Is `getOrientation()` ever called?

Comment: yes, the last line in the IF procedure      'SensorManager.getOrientation(mRemapedRotationMatrix, mOrientation);'

Comment: My question was is it ever called?  How do you know?  Put a breakpoint on that line.  Is it reached?

Comment: it gets called and holds the value "[F@40d85c00" when in landscape mode and a similar one in portrait. However the values changes every time I change back.

Comment: `[F@40d85c00 when in landscape mode and a similar one in portrait.` What holds the value? What do you mean, similar?  A different value for portrait and landscape?  The value you are seeing is not the value, just the memory address of whatever it is you're looking at.  Use the debugger window to see the value.